# How to apply exponential transformation to the predictions from a forecast object in R

Tags: r, transformation, forecast

I have made an arima model with *auto.arima*. Then I can obtain a forecast object by using the *forecast* function.

The issue is that I have applied a log transformation to the variable in order to reduce heteroscedasticity. Now the predictions are on the same scale as the log. I want to get the predictions in the actual scale, by taking an exponential transformation, and then plot the same graph we can obtain with a forecast object. But I cannot apply this transformation to a forecast object.

```r
arimaFit <- auto.arima(datats)
plot(exp(forecast(arimaFit, h = 100)))
```

That gives me the following error:

```r
Error in exp(forecast(arimaFit)) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I have thought about converting the forecast object into a matrix, then taking the exponential, and then transform the matrix into a forecast object again, but I cannot find a way to do this.

Is there any way to convert data into exponential to obtain the same plot with the original data?

Comment: Before everything else, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You could exponentiate the mean, upper, lower and x fields of the forecast object, then plot the resulting object.

The x field contains the series you log-transformed and then ran the auto.arima() on. The mean field contains the forecast (in log-scale), while the upper and lower fields contain the confidence intervals (also in log-scale).

```
ff <- forecast(arimaFit, h = 100)
ff$x <- exp(ff$x)
ff$mean <- exp(ff$mean)
ff$lower <- exp(ff$lower)
ff$upper <- exp(ff$upper)
plot(ff)
```

Alternatively, you could pass the lambda=0 parameter into the auto.arima() function, which will log-transform your original data series and fit, then the forecast function will back-transform to scale back.